# Text in Top of a Cocoapods SideMenu

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, cocoapods

I have created a sidemenu using cocoapod. But there is a empty space on the top of my menu. I have tried disabling my navigation controller but it didn't worked. How to change color and put some text in there.
I want something like this.

[image: Sample SideMenu]

[image: My SideMenu]

Comment: What pod are you using and how did you try to disable navigation?

Comment: @vpoltave I am using a pod named 'SideMenu' and I disabled Navigation bar through SideMenuNavigationControllerDelegate. I need a text in the empty space.

Comment: _I disabled Navigation bar through SideMenuNavigationControllerDelegate_ - Add code please.

Comment: I found the solution. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @selvavignesh Please leave your answer under the question in that case.

Comment: sideMenu?.navigationItem.title = "Context"